# 2001 Jeep dash board not working

Tags: electrical, jeep

2001 Jeep Cherokee Sport

My gauges do not work at all unless I press the door lock switch and hold it. Then, they will work, but as soon as I let go, they quit again. Where do I start with this problem.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you clarify something? Your title indicates the dash doesn't work, but your question states gauges. Is it specific things that aren't working or everything on the dash is not working?

Comment: Do the overhead lights come on when you press the switch or is it just the instrument panel? Do the gauges work but don't light up? Do the lights come on but the gauges don't work? or do neither work?

Comment: there are numerous jeep specific sites where you might get more specific help. google naxj for example

Answer (score 1):

First find and check all the ground or earth connections for the dashboard - usually connected to the frame at the sides of the dash but hidden under the dash. Then, it may be a supply problem - have you checked all the fuses?